# youtube-dl how to download multiple playlists in individual folders

Tags: download, youtube, youtube-dl

With youtube-dl I can do

```
# Download YouTube playlist videos in separate directory indexed by video order in a playlist
$ youtube-dl -o '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwiyx1dc3P2JR9N8gQaQN_BCvlSlap7re
```

the above script downloads the playlist by creating a folder with the name of the playlist and then downloads the individual videos into that folder.

I also can do

```
$ youtube-dl -citw --batch-file=downloads.txt
```

this script downloads all the video urls list in the batch file, the file can contain playlists as well as individual url's and `youtube-dl` downloads all videos in the current directory.

I now somehow want to marry both of these.
If i have a text file containing playlist links. I want to download all those playlist in to its own folder like I do with the 1st command.

Can I do that with `youtube-dl` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If downloads.txt contains one url per line try:

```
cat downloads.txt | xargs -n1 youtube-dl -o '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

Comment: yes I have one url per line ... and I should have mentiond it earlier but i'm doing this on a windows system..

Comment: Either install `cygwin` and use that line above, or install microsoft `powershell` and ask a new question how to translate that line to powershell.

Comment: In `powershell` you can do `$downloadLinks = Get-Content download.txt` and then loop thru each of those lines using `foreach($downloadLink in $downloadLinks)` and then do whatever processing you want in the `foreach` loop

Comment: this works so well.

Answer (score 1):

In case people from the future stumbled upon this post, I've found a solution working on Windows. Don't know about other OS though.

In your `x:\Users\USERNAME\` , create or edit a file named `youtube-dl.conf` and paste the commands below. This would always run in youtube-dl so you don't have to type it in the terminal. For more [info about the config file](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#configuration).

```
-o '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

After that, create a text file containing the playlist links separated by a line and run this.

```
youtube-dl --batch-file=downloads.txt
```

After downloading, you're free to delete the commands in `youtube-dl.conf`if you don't need it.

Comment: The config file is not a necessary part of this - you can simply include the `-o` switch when running the command on the command line. The config file is for command-line switches you use often enough to avoid typing them on the command line. I would also recommend anyone using YouTube-DL in 2021 to migrate to the [`yt-dlp`](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) fork, which is actively developed, more reliable, and much more fully featured. The sole developer of YouTube-DL went on a very long hiatus leaving the project essentially buried compared to the work other forks have done on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for Windows and Linux:

```
yt-dlp -o "%(playlist_title)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s" --batch-file=downloads.txt
```

This will create subfolders per playlist with the playlist name as the folder name.
Non-playlist videos will get downloaded to a folder named "NA".

Read more about youtube-dl output template here:
https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template